# powershell executing visual basic code from within jobs

Tags: powershell, jobs

im trying to launch the code below as a job but I do not think that I am initializing the assemblies correctly within the job.

the block below is what i want to execute within a job from powershell

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.VisualBasic") 
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox("DART Report completed.", "okonly,MsgBoxSetForeground,Information,DefaultButton2", "Report")
```

This is me trying to execute a simular block of code, when it finishes it appears to give me a powershell pop-up, not like the code block above.

```
$script:job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($HostName, $username)
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms, System.Reflection.Assembly, Microsoft.VisualBasic
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.VisualBasic") 
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox("Report completed.", "okonly + vbExclamation,MsgBoxSetForeground,Information,DefaultButton2", "DART Report")} -ArgumentList ($HostName, $username)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script requires some corrections:

1. You should add System.Reflection and not System.Reflection.Assembly
2. The second parameter for MsgBox should be quote separated vb options and you should not mix `Information` and `Exclamation` for a vb DialogBox.

Here is the rectified script :

```
$script:job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($HostName, $username)
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms, System.Reflection, Microsoft.VisualBasic
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.VisualBasic")
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox("Report completed.", "okonly,MsgBoxSetForeground,Exclamation,DefaultButton2", "DART Report")} -ArgumentList  ($HostName, $username)
```

It should prompt you a correct **Exclamation** dialog box. If you want a similar Dialog from your first powershell two lines, you have to replace `Exclamation` with `Information`.

**EDIT:** As @mklement0 states in the comment, `[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.VisualBasic")` isn't required in your script. It's logically also the same for the type `System.Reflection` and `System.Windows.Forms`, even if you want to use reflection later.

Here is the revised corresponding script :

```
$script:job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($HostName, $username)
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox("Report completed.", "okonly,MsgBoxSetForeground,Exclamation,DefaultButton2", "DART Report")} -ArgumentList  ($HostName, $username)
```

Comment: Good points, but it's worth mentioning that `[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.VisualBasic")` isn't needed, and that `Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic` is the only prerequisite for making the `[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox(...)` call work (and even that isn't required in PowerShell (Core) 7+). Also, please consider removing the command-continuation prompts (`>>`) from your answer, so as to allow others to simply copy-paste your code in order to run it.

Comment: Thanks you guys this completely cleared up my issue. I can finally have this job notify me and have it pop-up so i can see it. Thank you very much!!!!!